# Convergence of Limiting Matrix

Tags: limits, markov-chains, markov-process, dynamic-programming, hidden-markov-models

If the matrix $A_n$ is a markov transition matrix. Literature define de limiting matrix as $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} A_n $$ where $\{A_n, n= 0,1,2,... \}$ is a sequence if matrices. My question is if $$ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} A_n$$ exist, the limit above also exist? I think the answer is yes but I am not sure. The both limits are equals? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is true for sequences of real numbers, complex numbers, and matrices too. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the inconvenience.